# Generating the weak topology from half-spaces

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces

Is the weak topology on a complex Hilbert space $H$ the smallest topology that contains all the sets of the form : 
$\{x: Real(\langle v,x\rangle) < r\}$ where $v\in H$ and $r\in \mathbb{R}$ ?

Comment: Are you sure? Since a translation gives another space of the same type, just replacing $r$ by $r-Real(\langle v,a\rangle)$, where $a$ is the translation vector.